# Layout gets hidden sometimes hidden under mapview in Android

Tags: android, view, hide, android-mapview

I am displaying a custom view on tap of mapview. That view is in another xml layout file and that layout file is included in the xml layout in which the mapview is there.

For example, the custom view file is map_tool_tip.xml and the map screen is mapscreen.xml. In mapscreen.xml the code is written as below :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="05HCG9bJJ4yk-8qGcV1_LoEI4J499NRLnkQIIlQ" 
    />

    <include android:id="@+id/layoutMapToolTip" 
        layout="@layout/map_tool_tip"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout tool tip visibility is set to GONE and is changed only on Tap. Now, sometimes what happens is that tool tip never gets visible. I guess, its gets under mapview. I am not sure what the issue is. But it do not occurs each and everytime but it does happens.

What can be the issue for tooltip not getting visible and solution to that?

Comment: Are you sure your onTap method is only getting called once? I'm guessing that sometimes your phone is sending two onTap events when you would like only one. Not sure though.

Comment: Yes it does gets called once. On Doubletap the map zooms in. So that's not happening and it's getting called only once.

Comment: I guess sometimes what is happening is that layoutMapToolTip layout is going behind the mapview. Is there anyway that this can be prevented?